# How do I manually loop an html5 video in iOS 4.3/5?

Tags: ios, ipad, html, video

I have a video that has certain segments that need to be looped.  My problem is that on iOS 5, after the third time I update `videoElem.currentTime`, mobile safari stops updating that attribute.

On iOS 4.3, it seems to stop working intermittently.  What is causing `currentTime` to break and what are some workarounds?

Btw, I've tried setting the `currentTime` to floats with only one decimal & I've tried to set it to >0.  Neither has yielded any success.

Sample code:

```
window.setInterval(startTimer, 50); //ms

// function to begin the timer
var frameNum = 0;
function startTimer() {

  frameNum++;

  if (frameNum % 5 === 0)
  {
    console.log(videoElem.currentTime);
  }

  if (videoElem.currentTime >= 7) {
    videoElem.currentTime = 1;
    videoElem.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: you are very close to answer. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following event listener in JavaScript ( [Source](http://blog.millermedeiros.com/2011/03/html5-video-issues-on-the-ipad-and-how-to-solve-them/) ):

**UPDATE:** play 1 - 7 seconds in infinite loop

```
function restartVideo(){
    videoElem.currentTime = 0.1; //setting to zero breaks iOS 3.2, the value won't update, values smaller than 0.1 was causing bug as well.
    videoElem.play();
}
function videoTick(){
    if(videoElem.currentTime > 7) {
        restartVideo();
    }
}

// check progress every 1 second
window.setInterval(videoTick, 1000);
```

See demo link in iDevice : http://raptor.hk/dev/video.html

**UPDATE 2:** video controls of the video in demo link is removed. Still working in iOS.

Comment: That still doesn't work.  The video isn't necessarily ending at 7 seconds.  I need to loop segments (e.g 1 -7 of a 20 second video) so the ended event doesn't fire.

Comment: Updated based on your comments.

Comment: Actually, I found out that if you remove the 'controls' tag, it doesn't work.  CurrentTime doesn't update anymore

Comment: No. See the updated the demo link. Still working in iOS Safari.